# jQuery looping only works on last row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to show the results of the status of a bidding item using jQuery every second on every row in MySQL table, however only the result of the last row of the table is returned.

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT item, description, price, imageData, status, username, item_id FROM items"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$z=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
    //echo other columns here//
    echo "<td><div id=status$z></div></td>";

    ?>

    <script type=text/javascript>
        function updatestatus(itemnum)
        {
            var url="updatestatus.php?auc=<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>";
            jQuery('#status' + itemnum).load(url);  
        }

        setInterval("updatestatus(<? echo $z?>)", 1000);
    </script>

    <?   

    $z++;

}

?>
```

When I view source in the browser, the values for #status and auc for every row are correct. What am I missing here?

Here's the code for updatestatus.php

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once("connect.php");

    $id = $_GET['auc'];
    $getstatus = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM items WHERE item_id = '$id'  ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($getstatus);

    echo"$row[status]";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks good, save for the fact that it looks like you're creating multiple references to your `updatestatus()` function.

In Javascript, if you create multiple functions with the same name, calling them will only result in one of them running, usually the first or last one (depending on the implementation), so all the code you need to run in those functions needs to sit together in *one* function body.

If you're determined to use the code you've created, you'd need to throw all those update calls into one function body. There would be better ways to achieve what you need, but doing it with the code you've created, this would probably work better:

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT item, description, price, imageData, status, username, item_id FROM items";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $javascript = "";
    $z=0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

        //echo other columns here//
        echo "<td><div id=status$z></div></td>";

        // build the javascript to be put in the function later over here...
        $javascript .= "jQuery('#status". $z ."').load('updatestatus.php?auc=". $row['item_id'] ."');";

        $z++;

    }

?>
```

...and then further down the page, create the javascript (modified slightly):

```
<script type=text/javascript>

    function updatestatus()
    {
        <?php echo $javascript; ?>
    }

    setInterval(updatestatus, 1000);

</script>
```

So you're basically building up the Javascript that you'll need in your function, echoing it out inside the function body, and then setting the interval will call all that code, in this case, every second.

Like I said, there are definitely more efficient ways to achieve what you're trying to do, but this should work fine for now. I hope this makes sense, but please let me know if you need any clarity on anything! :)

Comment: I think I've done that. When I viewed the source in browser, I can see the Javascript running for every row in the table.

Comment: Was the entire function recreated several times, or just the `jQuery.load()` lines? Also, do all the status divs have unique IDs? I know it might sound lame, but I've made that mistake before myself ;)

Comment: the entire function is recreated on each row of result. yes the status and auc values are all unique

Comment: If the entire function is recreated repeatedly, trying to call it will only result in calling the first instance of it, thus only running the contents of the first instance and only affecting the first div surely? Could you perhaps edit your question and add all of the relevant PHP / Javascript code to help us help a bit better?

Comment: Hmm. You may have made a good point there. I've updated the question with the relevant codes. Only started out Php and Javscript a month ago, hope you dont mind helping a helpless and clueless chap!

Comment: Haha no man, don't be silly, we all start somewhere and it's because if the help I received once upon a time that I'm able to help you now :) I've edited my answer, hope it helps steer you in the right direction!

Comment: You Sir, are a genius! I'll take some time to digest that. Once again, thank you so much.

Comment: Haha too much practice more like! It's a pleasure, and keep coding!

Comment: By the way, I've noticed that if I change the code to this    setInterval(updatestatus(), 1000); it doesnt seem to work. Can you explain?

Comment: The `setInterval` function is looking for a reference to a function, not a function call. Adding the `()` means you're trying to call the function, not pass it as a reference. If you wanted to call that function with some parameters, you could use this syntax: `setInterval(function(){updatestatus("param1", "param2");}, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you're populating data using a incrementor. Is this supposed to be adding content to a page or replacing the content? from what it looks like it will just display one item, and then replace that one item with the next until it's done, which is why you see only the last row.

OR ...

the jquery update isn't being fed the $i variable .. change the function to

function updatestatus(itemnum) {

and then jquery echo to jQuery('#status' + itemnum).load(url);

then you can add the on-click/ or whatever to include the number 
onclick='updatestatus("1")'

on the other hand you might be needing to pass the total number of items to the function and then creating an if there to cycle through them (not tested, but you get the idea i hope)

```
 function updatestatus(numitems) {
    var url = "";
    var itemID = "";
    for (i = 1; i <= numitems; i++) {
        itemid = getElementById('#status'+numitems).getAttribute("itemID")
        url="updatestatus.php?auc="+itemID;
        jQuery('#status'+numitems).load(url);    
    }
 }

setInterval("updatestatus()", 1000);
```

and the html element for "#status1" as created by the PHP should look like this:

```
<div id="status1" itemid="23455">
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated the code using function updatestatus(itemnum) { var url="updatestatus.php?auc=<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>"; jQuery('#status' + itemnum).load(url); } setInterval("updatestatus(<? echo $i ?>)", 1000); Now, the results are showing on every row. However, the results are all the same on each row.

Comment: For the incrementor, I used $i=0; while($row=mysql_fetch_array(result)){
echo "<td><div id=status$i /></td>";
$i++; }